# WAI-ARIA attribute needs a unique id, however this react component might be created multiple times

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to create an Accordion component with WAI-ARIA attributes, however, some elements are required to reference a unique id. In this case, the Accordion's content (`accordion__content`) has to have a unique id that is referenced by the button's attribute `aria-controls`.

Since the component might be used multiple times in different places within the page, using 'any-id' as an id would not work.

```
type AccordionProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  label: string;
};

export const Accordion = ({ label, children }: AccordionProps) => {
  const { isContentShowing, setIsContentShowing } = useAccordion();

  return (
    <div className="accordion" aria-label={`${label} Accordion`} data-testid="accordion">
      <button
        className="accordion__button"
        onClick={setIsContentShowing}
        aria-expanded={isContentShowing}
        aria-controls="UNIQUE-ID"
      >
        <span className="accordion__text">{label}</span>
        <AccordionArrowIcon isContentShowing={isContentShowing} />
      </button>
      {isContentShowing && (
        <div className="accordion__content" id="UNIQUE-ID" aria-hidden={!isContentShowing}>
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

One option would be to generate a random id and just assign that id to the attributes, or we could also take the id as a prop. Is there any recommended way for doing this?

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've had problems like this in the past, I've generated a uuid for the component. That would make your code like this:

```
import React from "react";
// This is the library I'd use, but feel free to make up the ID however you want
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';

type AccordionProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  label: string;
};

export const Accordion = ({ label, children }: AccordionProps) => {
  const { isContentShowing, setIsContentShowing } = useAccordion();
  // Note that the ID will be regenerated on every re-render, but will still stay internally consistent
  const id = uuid();

  return (
    <div className="accordion" aria-label={`${label} Accordion`} data-testid="accordion">
      <button
        className="accordion__button"
        onClick={setIsContentShowing}
        aria-expanded={isContentShowing}
        aria-controls={id}
      >
        <span className="accordion__text">{label}</span>
        <AccordionArrowIcon isContentShowing={isContentShowing} />
      </button>
      {isContentShowing && (
        <div className="accordion__content" id={id} aria-hidden={!isContentShowing}>
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Also, your `aria-hidden` isn't doing anything. There's logically no point where it would be true, since the element doesn't exist when the content isn't showing.

Comment: I think would be the best approach tbh, just didn't like generating the Id on every render, but it seems to be the only option. Also, changed the accordion's content to be hidden instead of not rendering the content at all. Thanks!